# Configure Azure credentials on Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed the Jenkins server on my local machine.

After I installed the Azure plugin on jenkins server, I added the credentials of Azure on jenkins server from Credentials -> System -> Global Credentials.

Took the Subscription ID from the webapp created on the Azure portal.

Then gone to Azure Active Directory -> App registration -> Add, and registered the app by giving new Name and URL.

Took the Client ID from the newly created application's `Application ID`.

And then gone in Keys section and created a new key to get the Client Secret.

After that Tenant ID got from Properties -> Directory ID. (To put this in OAuth token `https://login.windows.net/<TokenID>`).

Now after entering all these details, when I click on `Verify Service Principal`, I am getting the error:-

> The provided credentials are not valid.

Comment: I think i got the answer here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/jenkins/jenkins-azure-vm-agents  

Its better to leave the storaage account name as new and blank in order to create a new one for this node and it works

Comment: Please post a proper answer *as an answer* so that this question can be closed correctly.

Comment: subscription id has nothing to do with the app. its your account id. i just follow jenkins links in the help buttons (?) and it works. u can see the subscription id when login to the cli via 'az login'. the tenant id also appears there